# How to copy all files and folders in specific directory using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I have one folder in adls gen2 say it as mysource1 folder .. which has 100's of subfolder s and each subfolder again contains folders and many files ..

How can I copy all of the folders and files in mysource1 using azure data factory ..

Comment: Hi @maddy, welcome to stack overflow.  If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You could use binary as source format. It will help you copy all the folders and files in source to sink.

For example: this is my container `test`:
[image]

**Source dataset:**
[image]

**Sink dataset:**
[image]

**Copy active:**
[image]

**Output:**
[image]

You can follow my steps.

Answer (score 0):

use ingest tab on ADF Home page, there you could specify source location using linked service and target location